# sort and uniq in python

Tags: python, shell, sorting

I want to do some shell command in python. I have a main.py, which call successive function and I find some of them easier to do in shell. The problem : I want to do all of this automatically !

I want to do this kind of code :

```
sort fileIn | uniq > fileOut
```

my problem is to do it with the pipe caracter. I try :

```
from subprocess import call
call(['sort ',FileOut,'|',' uniq '])
```

or

```
 p1 = subprocess.Popen(['sort ', FileOut], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen([" wc","-l"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output,err = p2.communicate()
```

But all of this didn't work. 
(NB: FileOut is a string)

Comment: The second example works fine for me if I remove the extra whitespace after`'sort '` and before `" wc"`.

Comment: You may be interested in [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [shell](http://shell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), or even the built-in [pipes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pipes.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `shell=True`, which causes your command to be run by the shell, instead of using a `exec` syscall:

```
call('sort {0} | uniq'.format(FileOut), shell=True)
```

It's worth noting that, if you simply want unique lines of a file in python (in no particular order), it may be easier to do so **without** the shell:

```
unique_lines= set(open('filename').readlines())
```

Comment: Note that you should only use `shell=True` with trusted input, otherwise its a security risk.

Comment: @dano I'd argue that running processes named from untrusted input is always unsafe, `shell=True` or otherwise. `shell=False` only protects you from the attacker faking more than one argument when you only expect one.

Comment: @goncalopp `shell=True` can let an attacker run arbitrary commands. That's not possible with `shell=False`. For example, if `FileOut` was `"& touch uhoh.txt"`, running the command would result in `uhoh.txt` being created (on Linux, at least).

Comment: `set` can be initialized with an iterable, so `set(open('filename'))` should suffice. I'd do `with open('filename') as f: unique_lines = set(f)` though

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of always looking up the Popen module documentation so this is an abridged version of the utility function I use to wrap Popen. you can take the so parameter of the first call and pass it as the input to the next call. You can also do error checking/parsing if you need to.

```
def run(command, input=None)
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    if input:
        so, se = process.communicate(input)
    else:
        so, se = process.communicate()
    rc = process.returncode
    return so, se, rc
```

Comment: [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), introduced on 2.7, helps a lot in this regard, though your version may be more useful in some cases